# Installing sublime text 3 on AWS Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: sublimetext3, ubuntu-14.04

[Sublime-text is a fast editor for Windows and Linux](http://www.sublimetext.com/). I failed to install sublime text 3 on AWS Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Results in following error message:

```
p: cannot create regular file "/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/": 
No such file or directory dpkg: error processing package sublime-text-installer (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

I see following directories under /usr/share/icons/hicolor/
32
48
64
So, I created 16x16 subdirectory, but then it gives an error for 32x32 directory doesnot exist. Did anyone experience this problem before? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: did you figure this out?  Got the same error and trying to debug. Thanks!

Comment: To Kishor Patel. You should delete the folders you created manually before running my solution.

Answer (score 4):

sublime-text is a GUI application that needs a GTK installation. Your server is missing that dependency. (In a perfect world, it should be a dependency of the package of course.)

Install libgtk2 (as root):

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-common
```

and then reinstall sublime-text, probably using:

```
apt-get purge sublime-text-installer ; apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Comment: I had the same problem with Sublime 2 on Ubuntu 14 minimal version, this solved it