# Sublime Text 3 installation with GTK library fails on AWS Ubuntu 16.04.03 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, gtk, sublimetext3, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install Sublime Text 3 on an AWS Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS instance according to the instructions provided by the link: [Install Sublime Text 3 in Ubuntu 16.04 & Higher The Official Way](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/05/30/install-sublime-text-3-ubuntu-16-04-official-way/).

After the installation attempt failed I found the related link: [Installing sublime text 3 on AWS Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867839/installing-sublime-text-3-on-aws-ubuntu-14-04-1-lts)
 and I used it to install the missing GTK library.

The sequence was as follows:

```
userid@serverip:~$ wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
[sudo] password for userid:
OK
userid@serverip:~$
userid@serverip:~$
userid@serverip:~$ echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
userid@serverip:~$
userid@serverip:~$
userid@serverip:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for userid:
Hit:1 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:3 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Get:4 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [699 kB]
Get:5 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [572 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:7 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease [2,562 B]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Sources [106 kB]
Get:9 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages [729 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [424 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [186 kB]
Fetched 2,296 kB in 1s (1,456 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
userid@serverip:~$ sudo apt-get install sublime-text
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1022 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1038 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1039 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1041
  linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1043 linux-headers-4.4.0-1022-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1038-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1039-aws
  linux-headers-4.4.0-1041-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1043-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1022-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1038-aws
  linux-image-4.4.0-1039-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1041-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1043-aws
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sublime-text
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,190 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ sublime-text 3143 [8,190 kB]
Fetched 8,190 kB in 1s (4,802 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package sublime-text.
(Reading database ... 244000 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../sublime-text_3143_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking sublime-text (3143) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up sublime-text (3143) ...
userid@serverip:~$
```

But when I invoked Sublime Text:

```
userid@serverip:~$ subl
```

the response was:

```
Unable to load libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_cairo_create from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_cursor_new_for_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_cursor_unref from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_display_get_default from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_display_get_pointer from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_error_trap_pop from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_error_trap_push from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_input_add from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_input_remove from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_keymap_translate_keyboard_state from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_keyval_to_unicode from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_region_get_rectangles from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_default from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_height from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_rgb_colormap from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_rgba_colormap from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_root_window from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_width from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_n_monitors from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_monitor_at_point from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_monitor_geometry from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_resolution from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_unicode_to_keyval from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_get_frame_extents from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_get_origin from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_get_state from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_invalidate_rect from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_set_cursor from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_move_resize from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_get_server_time from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_get_xatom_by_name_for_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_window_set_user_time from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_accel_group_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_accelerator_get_default_mod_mask from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_box_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_box_pack_start from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_new_with_label from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_set_active from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_clear from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_get from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_set_text from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_set_with_data from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_store from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_wait_for_text from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_container_add from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_container_get_children from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_container_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_container_remove from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_dialog_add_button from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_dialog_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_dialog_run from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_dialog_set_default_response from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_drag_dest_set from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_drag_finish from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_add_filter from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_get_filename from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_get_files from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_current_name from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_do_overwrite_confirmation from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_local_only from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_select_multiple from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_filter_add_pattern from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_filter_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_filter_set_name from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_get_current_event_time from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_im_context_filter_keypress from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_im_context_set_client_window from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_im_multicontext_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_init from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_init_check from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_main from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_main_quit from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_attach_to_widget from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_bar_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_get_label from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_get_submenu from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_new_with_label from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_set_label from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_set_submenu from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_set_use_underline from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_popup from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_shell_append from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_shell_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_message_dialog_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_message_dialog_new_with_markup from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_selection_data_get_uris from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_selection_data_set_text from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_separator_menu_item_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_settings_get_default from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_show_uri from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_vbox_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_add_accelerator from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_add_events from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_destroy from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_display from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_parent from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_screen from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_window from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_grab_focus from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_hide from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_remove_accelerator from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_set_app_paintable from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_set_colormap from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_set_double_buffered from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_set_sensitive from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_show from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_show_all from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_size_request from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_add_accel_group from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_fullscreen from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_iconify from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_maximize from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_move from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_present_with_time from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_remove_accel_group from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_resize from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_default_icon_list from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_default_size from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_keep_above from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_modal from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_position from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_title from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_transient_for from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_type_hint from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_stick from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_unfullscreen from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_modify_bg from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_decorated from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_skip_taskbar_hint from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_skip_pager_hint from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
userid@serverip:~$
```

So I tried installing the missing library libgtk2.0-0:

```
userid@serverip:~$ apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
[sudo] password for userid:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1022 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1038 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1039 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1041
  linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1043 linux-headers-4.4.0-1022-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1038-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1039-aws
  linux-headers-4.4.0-1041-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1043-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1022-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1038-aws
  linux-image-4.4.0-1039-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1041-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1043-aws
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  hicolor-icon-theme libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common
  libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxrandr2
Suggested packages:
  librsvg2-common gvfs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hicolor-icon-theme libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin
  libgtk2.0-common libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxrandr2
0 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,258 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,150 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libxcomposite1 amd64 1:0.4.4-1 [7,714 B]
Get:2 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libxdamage1 amd64 1:1.1.4-2 [6,946 B]
Get:3 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libxfixes3 amd64 1:5.0.1-2 [11.1 kB]
Get:4 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libxinerama1 amd64 2:1.1.3-1 [7,908 B]
Get:5 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 hicolor-icon-theme all 0.15-0ubuntu1 [7,750 B]
Get:6 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libatk1.0-data all 2.18.0-1 [17.1 kB]
Get:7 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libatk1.0-0 amd64 2.18.0-1 [56.9 kB]
Get:8 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common all 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3 [10.4 

kB]
Get:9 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 amd64 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3 [159 kB]
Get:10 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgtk2.0-common all 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2 [123 

kB]
Get:11 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libxcursor1 amd64 1:1.1.14-1ubuntu0.16.04.1 [20.2 

kB]
Get:12 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libxi6 amd64 2:1.7.6-1 [28.6 kB]
Get:13 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libxrandr2 amd64 2:1.5.0-1 [17.6 kB]
Get:14 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgtk2.0-0 amd64 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2 [1,775 

kB]
Get:15 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgtk2.0-bin amd64 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2 [9,834 

B]
Fetched 2,258 kB in 0s (20.4 MB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libxcomposite1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 244086 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libxcomposite1_1%3a0.4.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcomposite1:amd64 (1:0.4.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxdamage1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxdamage1_1%3a1.1.4-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxdamage1:amd64 (1:1.1.4-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxfixes3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxfixes3_1%3a5.0.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxfixes3:amd64 (1:5.0.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxinerama1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxinerama1_2%3a1.1.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxinerama1:amd64 (2:1.1.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package hicolor-icon-theme.
Preparing to unpack .../hicolor-icon-theme_0.15-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libatk1.0-data.
Preparing to unpack .../libatk1.0-data_2.18.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libatk1.0-data (2.18.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libatk1.0-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libatk1.0-0_2.18.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libatk1.0-0:amd64 (2.18.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common.
Preparing to unpack .../libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common_2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0_2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgtk2.0-common.
Preparing to unpack .../libgtk2.0-common_2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgtk2.0-common (2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxcursor1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxcursor1_1%3a1.1.14-1ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcursor1:amd64 (1:1.1.14-1ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxi6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxi6_2%3a1.7.6-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxi6:amd64 (2:1.7.6-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxrandr2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxrandr2_2%3a1.5.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxrandr2:amd64 (2:1.5.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgtk2.0-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgtk2.0-0_2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgtk2.0-0:amd64 (2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgtk2.0-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../libgtk2.0-bin_2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgtk2.0-bin (2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libxcomposite1:amd64 (1:0.4.4-1) ...
Setting up libxdamage1:amd64 (1:1.1.4-2) ...
Setting up libxfixes3:amd64 (1:5.0.1-2) ...
Setting up libxinerama1:amd64 (2:1.1.3-1) ...
Setting up hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libatk1.0-data (2.18.0-1) ...
Setting up libatk1.0-0:amd64 (2.18.0-1) ...
Setting up libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libgtk2.0-common (2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...
Setting up libxcursor1:amd64 (1:1.1.14-1ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libxi6:amd64 (2:1.7.6-1) ...
Setting up libxrandr2:amd64 (2:1.5.0-1) ...
Setting up libgtk2.0-0:amd64 (2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...
Setting up libgtk2.0-bin (2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
userid@serverip:~$
```

But after I once again tried invoking Sublime Text:

```
userid@serverip:~$ subl
userid@serverip:~$
```

There was no response at all...

I don't know what I am missing now so any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have ever met the issue.

my sublime run on remote linux by ssh.

And `subl -x filename` will help you.(only in MobaXterm)

Another way is **map the Linux directory to the network drive**, you can open any file with sublime.

- install samba
  `apt-get install samba`
- modify configuration
  `vim /etc/samba/smb.conf`
- add in the last

  ```
  security=user
  [public]
  path=filename
  public=yes
  writeable=yes
  browseable=yes
  guest ok=yes
  ```
- `chmod 777 filename`
- `cd /etc/init.d/`
- `smbd restart`
- Finally, set the network drive